# How to call a java script function located in another module in mocha test case

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Suppose, I have a.js located in xyz/module1 path. I want to call checkEmpty function in my mocha test case located in xyz/module2.
a.js :

```
function checkEmpty(val){
  if(val != null && val != ""){
    return false;
  }
 return true;
}
```

testcase.js:

```
describe('testcase', function () {
  var val = "";
  it('Validating empty string', () => {
    //call checkEmpty
  });
});
```

I can achieve it by exporting the function in a.js but I don't want to use the export statement. Can someone help me with this?